# Get only updated data from API

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, fetch

I'm a beginner in Swift and I'm building my first app that fetches some data from server. Everything is working well, but I'm now thinking how to make my app get only the updated data. Are there any tutorials, examples, or ideas that could help me understand the mechanism and the right method to achieve my goal?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could have searched and tried something out for that first before posting here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to do that, however you will need to add the code to your server. I would recommend checking the old data set against the new one and then sending the ones that weren't in the first data set. I would recommend researching storing data in whichever language you're server code is in.

Answer (score 0):

That approach is the best approach for app and server for iOS app, for minimum data transfer for both server and app.

But you need to do an extra work to achieve that and the approach is not exactly what you've described.

First within the app.

- Your approach:

  1. You to keep on track which was changes and which was not.
  2. Inform the server about the changes then push the filtered data back to the app.
     (If you are planning to just store those changed values in memory that is not a good idea.)
- Ideal appeach:

  1. Probably a database for "changed values" and the database "from server values" which is the original data gathered from server.
  2. Update the "from server values" database locally within the app.
  3. Then inform the server about the changes you made and just save it there.
     (You dont need to request for some changed data, because you already handled it locally)
  4. Then have some notification(using socket) to inform other users about the changes made, then other user will request from server for updated values, then so on..